# Driving a Mexican plated car in Canada

Tags: canada, driving

I am a Canadian citizen living in Mexico with a status of a permanent resident FM2 card with a house a Mexican drivers license and my truck which is originally from Canada has been imported to Mexico and is legally registered and has Mexican plates with vehicle insurance. My question is can I drive my vehicle to Canada from Mexico and enter Canada for a 1 or 2 month vacation. I believe that I may have to up my Liability coverage to at least $200,000 Canadian or more.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  Which province(s) will you be driving in?  Registration & insurance regulations are largely handled at the provincial level and can vary from province to province.

Comment: Ask your insurance provider whether they cover in Canada or USA.  If they say yes, get it in writing and carry it with you.  Without evidence in English, US officials will assume you’re uninsured..

Answer (score 3):

Ask your insurance provider whether they cover in Canada or USA.  If they say yes, get it in writing and carry it with you.  Without evidence in English, US officials will assume you’re uninsured.

If they say no, you can get coverage by the day from a travel insurance company.  I’ve always got mine from Allianz, but there are many others.

Comment: False assumptions don't necessarily result in penalties, but it can be a big nuisance to have to go a long ways away to argue your way out of a fine!